# update one row in per group

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here I have a table :

```
+------+------+-------+------+----------+
| id   | year | val   | row  | whatever |
+------+------+-------+------+----------+
| 001  | 2006 |  8    |    1 | p01      |
| 001  | 2003 |  -10  |    2 | p01      |
| 001  | 2008 |  5    |    3 | p01      |
| 001  | 2001 |  -2   |    4 | p01      |
| 002  | 2007 |  5    |    1 | p01      |
| 002  | 2009 |  4    |    2 | p01      |
| 002  | 2002 |  -5   |    3 | p01      |
| 002  | 2004 |  -4   |    4 | p01      |
| 003  | 2005 |  15   |    1 | p01      |
| 003  | 2000 |  -18  |    2 | p01      |
| 003  | 2001 |  -12  |    3 | p02      |
| 003  | 2004 |  12   |    4 | p02      |
| 003  | 2002 |  12   |    5 | p02      |
| 004  | 2003 |  5    |    1 | p02      |
| 004  | 2000 |  -8   |    2 | p02      |
| 004  | 2006 |  4    |    3 | p02      |
| 004  | 2007 |  3    |    4 | p02      |
+------+------+-------+------+----------+
```

I want in per group by id, sum of vals=0, if vals <> 0, so result of sum in per group reduce with first vals. for example in id =1 ==> sum =(8)+(-10)+(5)+(-2)=1 , if val's row1 reduce 1, sum equal 0 and ok.

```
update mytable

set val=val-(
select sum(val) from my table
group by id
)

where row=1
```

What is the correct solution in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window version of `SUM` to calculate the sum of `val` for each `id` partition. Then wrap your query in a CTE and update the CTE:

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT id, row, val, SUM(val) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS sumVal
   FROM mytable
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET val = val - sumVal
WHERE row = 1
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a131d/1)

Comment: @zahra Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.